# Request forms based authentication protected url from windows service on same machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-services, forms-authentication

I have an MVC3 website using forms authentication.  On the same server is a windows service.

Both share the same database (which includes the standard asp.net membership tables) and they also share code up to the service layer.

I have a need for the windows service to be able to impersonate any membership user and then call a url on the website as that user.  I'm not calling the url personally, it's called via a component which coverts URL output to a PDF.

I don't have the passwords because they're hashed in the database, so what I need is to be able to get a valid aspxauth cookie and send it with my request.

I've had no joy so far.  Every PDF which is made is just a copy of my login screen.

Is it possible to generate a valid ticket from the windows service, which the website will accept and act as if that user had actually been through the login process?

Thanks.

Comment: authentication works with cookies, so I think it's better that you create the models what you need to pass to service and then do what you want.

Comment: I can't do that because once called, that page actually makes further calls for things.  I'm currently trying to generate a valid ticket inside the windows service and put it into a cookie (.ASPXAUTH).  Should it be possible to create a ticket from the windows server for user "bob.smith" and have that ticket accepted on the website via the aspxauth cookie, if the windows service and the website use the same machinekey, validationkey and decryptionkey, or am I missing something?

Comment: It turned out that is just didn't work if I tried to send the cookie using EVO's pdf converter.  By sending it manually in the HttpHeaders collection instead, it worked.  I'm not going mad after all. :)